# Blazor Wasm call SatehHasChanged every second. lagging

Tags: asp.net-core, optimization, blazor-webassembly

```
Parallel.Invoke(_po, async () => {
                while(!_viewModel.DisConnect)
                {
                    await _viewModel.SetThings();
                    await InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged());
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
            });
```

UI:

```
@foreach(var rsi in _viewModel.things)
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-center">
                <span>Code: @things.Code</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col text-center">
                <span>value: @(Math.Truncate(things.Value * 10000) / 10000)</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

call Function and, call sateHasChanged every second for update UI.
it's lagging. When I hover the mouse, it reacts after a 1~2 seconds.

how to update UI data every second without lagging on blazor wasm?

Comment: Don't do that. Just don't. For starters, that `Parallel.Invoke` serves no purpose. `Parallel` is meant for data parallelism, but that `Invoke` doesn't run anything in parallel, it's effectively nothing more than a `Task.Run(...).Wait()`. Second, the method it calls makes no sense. `StateHasChanged` will be called automatically if data binding is used. If you used a `things` field instead of a nested property there would be no problem. Finally, the code is *freezing the browser tab*. There's only one thread per tab, that's why Blazor uses `async` everywhere

Comment: Instead of this code you could use a `Timer` and load the new data in its callback, storing it in a field. Even that isn't a great idea even though it won't freeze the browser. Polling to just get the same data, or just a few changed rows, is bad both for the browser and server. Use SignalR instead to *push* changes from the server to the browser. Instead of loading identical data every 1 second, you'd only get new data

Comment: As an add on to what  @PanagiotisKanavos says and his answer, `Thread.Sleep(1000);` blocks the single thread that WASM has, hence the delay.  You should always use `await Task.Delay(n)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is blocking itself. `Parallel.Invoke` is used to execute multiple operations in parallel in a *blocking* way, but the question's code only has a single operation. This is no better than `Task.Run(..).Wait()`. The delegate the tries to call the already blocked UI thread with `InvokeAsync()`. And then freezes the thread for 1 second.

It would be simpler and better to use a simple loop and `Task.Delay()` :

```
while(!_viewModel.DisConnect)
{
    await _viewModel.SetThings();
    StateHasChanged();
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

Even better, use a timer :

```
_timer = new System.Threading.Timer(async _ =>
        {
            await _viewModel.SetThings();
            StateHasChanged();
        },null, 0, 1000);
```

To stop the timer, call `Dispose()` when needed:

```
_timer.Dispose();
```